# django chart.js - Query to get count of all distinct values for particular column

Tags: python, django, chart.js

My goal is to create a query to group together unique 'charges' and count them. Then correctly implementing a for loop, which would in a pie chart showing multiple slices, each individual slice showing the total count per unique charge. My problem is using my current queries I run into the following **attribute error 'dict' object has no attribute 'charge'**. I have tried a few different ways to write the query and would appreciate feedback in writing a query or in my for loop.

```
# Models.py
class Arrest(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    charge = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

```
# Views.py
def visuals(request):
    data = []
    labels = []

    # The two queries I have tried.
    # queryset = Arrest.objects.values('charge').annotate(the_count=Count('charge'))
    # queryset = Arrest.objects.values('charge').order_by('charge').annotate(the_count=Count('charge'))
    
    for arrest in queryset:
        data.append(arrest.charge)
        labels.append(arrest.charge)

    return render(request, "data/visuals.html", {
    'labels': labels,
    'data': data,
    })
```

```
# Error
AttributeError at /visuals

'dict' object has no attribute 'charge'
```

```
# visuals.html
{% extends "data/layout.html" %}
{% block head %}
<title>Visuals</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
{% load static %}
<div class="title2">
  <h2>Visuals (include links for invdividuals graphs)</h2>
</div>
<div class="body-text">
  <div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
    <canvas id="pie-chart"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var config = {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: {{ data|safe }},
          backgroundColor: [
            '#696969', '#808080', '#A9A9A9', '#C0C0C0', '#D3D3D3'
          ],
          label: 'Population'
        }],
        labels: {{ labels|safe }}
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true
      }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById('pie-chart').getContext('2d');
      window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
  </script>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Added html. My Arrest object does have charge, is my error in my query then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution requires modifying views.py in two parts, a new query and converting to list. The JS is fine.

```
def visuals(request):
    queryset = Arrest.objects.order_by('charge').values('charge').annotate(charge_count=Count('charge'))

    data = list(queryset.values_list('charge_count', flat=True))
    labels = list(queryset.values_list('charge', flat=True))

    return render(request, "data/visuals.html", {
    'labels': labels,
    'data': data,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate), I think you might have to check once again. But this might be the solution.

```
queryset = Arrest.objects.annotate(Count('charge'))
for arrest in queryset:
    data.append(arrest.charge__count)
    labels.append(arrest.name)
```

Here, I assume that `labels` refers to the name of each data and change your original code.

Comment: Good news is a pie chart is being rendered and that documentation does seem to apply here, thank you. However the charges are not being counted up to a total per unique charge.